# Aren't the sectioning commands supposed to work inside longtable?

Tags: sectioning, longtable

Using sectioning commands such as **section**, **subsection** inside a **longtable** produce the following error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.
```

Is this normal?

Here is the code (created with LyX):

```
% Preview source code

%% LyX 1.6.7 created this file.  For more info, see http://www.lyx.org/.
%% Do not edit unless you really know what you are doing.
\documentclass[english]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}

\makeatletter

%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% LyX specific LaTeX commands.
%% Because html converters don't know tabularnewline
\providecommand{\tabularnewline}{\\}

\makeatother

\usepackage{babel}

\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|>{\centering}p{0.3\textwidth}|>{\raggedright}p{0.4\textwidth}|}
\hline 
\section*{Name} & \section*{Description}\tabularnewline
\hline
\hline 

a & b
\tabularnewline
\hline 
a & b

\tabularnewline
\hline 
a & b

\tabularnewline
\hline
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Actually, I never heard of using `\section` commands inside longtable.... In [this post](http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=3409) I found a workaround that worked.

Comment: @henrique I find it useful to have some cells containing headings (the astrisk versions to avoid having them in TOC). I checked the post you gave, but it's too complex, and Ulrike's solution below is simple & working.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Protect them:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[latin9]{inputenc}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{longtable}


\begin{document}
\begin{longtable}{|p{0.3\textwidth}|p{0.4\textwidth}|}
\protect\section*{Name} & \protect\section*{Description}
\end{longtable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working, however, I couldn't do it in LyX (`\section` precedes `\protect`), but this is an unrelated issue.

Comment: @John: You can try to make `\section` robust with `\usepackage{etoolbox}\robustify{\section}`. (I don't know if this has unwanted side effects.)

Comment: very nice post, I am working on a book that has 32 `longtables` and I was wondering if there is a way to add section and subsections to it and it worked.

Comment: For some reason both solutions don't work in my case. I use MiKTeX 2.9.

Comment: @Smylic My example still works fine for me in miktex (just tested). Beside this: "don't work" is my most hated problem description.

Comment: I mean I still have `! LaTeX Error: Something's wrong--perhaps a missing \item.`